# Recursively build JSON from two arrays

Tags: javascript, json

This for Material UI Treeview. I am trying to build a recursive function to dynamically build out the JSON from two arrays. The first array is the MainArray which would be the starting point. The second array is the directories array.

The goal is to pair the directories obj's to its parent in a new property named SubDirectories.

```
const mainArray = [{
  Id: 1,
  Name: "test",
  SubDirectoryCount: 10,
  Files: []
}]
```

```
const directories = [{
    Id: 56,
    Name: "Client 2",
    SubDirectoryCount: 1,
    ParentId: 1,
    Files: []
  },  {
    Id: 53,
    Name: "Client 3",
    SubDirectoryCount: 1,
    ParentId: 1,
    Files: []
  },
  {
    Id: 50,
    Name: "Client 4",
    SubDirectoryCount: 1,
    ParentId: 1,
    Files: []
  },
  {
    Id: 48,
    Name: "Client 5",
    SubDirectoryCount: 1,
    ParentId: 53,
    Files: []
  },
   {
    Id: 47,
    Name: "Client 5",
    SubDirectoryCount: 1,
    ParentId: 53,
    Files: []
  },
   {
    Id: 47,
    Name: "Client 5",
    SubDirectoryCount: 1,
    ParentId: 53,
    Files: []
  }]
```

What I have without recursion...

```
export const createTreeData = ( mainArray , directories ) => {


  for (let idx in mainArray) {

    if (directories ) {
      const directoriesList = [];

      directories.map((dir) => {
        if (mainArray.Id === dir.ParentId) {
          directoriesList.push(dir);
        }
      });
      mainArray.SubDirectories = directories;
    }
  }

  return mainArray ;

};
```

The final output:

```
  [{
      Id: 1,
      Name: "test",
      SubDirectoryCount: 10,
      Files: []
      *SubDirectories: [{ 
        Id: 56,
        Name: "Client 2",
        SubDirectoryCount: 1,
        ParentId: 1,
        Files: []
      },{
        Id: 53,
        Name: "Client 3",
        SubDirectoryCount: 1,
        ParentId: 1,
        Files: [],
        *SubDirectories:[{
            Id: 48,
            Name: "Client 5",
            SubDirectoryCount: 1,
            ParentId: 53,
            Files: []
          },
           {
            Id: 47,
            Name: "Client 5",
            SubDirectoryCount: 1,
            ParentId: 53,
            Files: []
          },
           {
            Id: 47,
            Name: "Client 5",
            SubDirectoryCount: 1,
            ParentId: 53,
            Files: []
          }]},
      {
        Id: 50,
        Name: "Client 4",
        SubDirectoryCount: 1,
        ParentId: 1,
        Files: []
      }
      ]
    }]
```

- New property

Comment: why `ParentFk: 53` and not `ParentId: 53` ?

Comment: ParentFk is supposed to be ParentId. typo. thanks!

Comment: Does it need to be recursive?

Comment: @GabrielBrito - I figure recursive would be best since it could go 3 to 4 even 5+ deep. I played around with a few other ideas but no dice...

Comment: Ah, I see you need recursion and updated the sample. Let me review my answer

Comment: @Django the disadvantage of going recursive here is that you will need to iterate your list multiple times to create a treelike structure and that can be problematic since depending on how your array is ordered you will need to handle multiple root elements to say the least. Please check if my answer fits your need.

Comment: do `Id`s always precede `ParentId`s (or is it possible to have a `parentId` without an`Id` existing before [or not at all]?)

Comment: Thanks everyone, I stress tested all the answers on this page and they all work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add directories to an associative array and remap each time.

```js
const directories = [{Id:56,Name:"Client 2",SubDirectoryCount:1,ParentId:1,Files:[]},{Id:53,Name:"Client 3",SubDirectoryCount:1,ParentId:1,Files:[]},{Id:50,Name:"Client 4",SubDirectoryCount:1,ParentId:1,Files:[]},{Id:48,Name:"Client 5",SubDirectoryCount:1,ParentId:53,Files:[]},{Id:47,Name:"Client 5",SubDirectoryCount:1,ParentId:53,Files:[]},{Id:49,Name:"Client 5",SubDirectoryCount:1,ParentId:53,Files:[]}];

const moreDirectories = [{Id:156,Name:"Client 12",SubDirectoryCount:1,ParentId:49,Files:[]},{Id:53,Name:"Client 334",SubDirectoryCount:1,ParentId:48,Files:[]},{Id:150,Name:"Client 14",SubDirectoryCount:1,ParentId:1,Files:[]},{Id:148,Name:"Client 15",SubDirectoryCount:1,ParentId:53,Files:[]},{Id:147,Name:"Client 15",SubDirectoryCount:1,ParentId:49,Files:[]},{Id:149,Name:"Client 51",SubDirectoryCount:1,ParentId:50,Files:[]}];

// keep a flatlist of all folders in memory
const flatlist = {
  1: {Id:1,Name:"test",SubDirectoryCount:10,Files:[]}
};

/**
 * Updates the flat map and returns the root
 * @param {Array} folder updates
 * @returns {Array} updated root
 */
const update = updates => {
  // append updates to flatlist
  updates.forEach(d => {
    flatlist[d.Id] = Object.assign(flatlist[d.Id] || {}, d);
  });

  // remove deleted folders?
  // ...

  // destroy existing sub-directories and create SubDirectories
  Object.values(flatlist).forEach(directory => directory.SubDirectories = []);

  // remap 
  Object.keys(flatlist).forEach(key => {
    const directory = flatlist[key];
    const parent = flatlist[directory.ParentId];
    if (parent) {
      parent.SubDirectories.push(directory);
    }
  });

  // return a new copy of the root directory
  return Object.assign({}, flatlist[1]);
};

update(directories)
update(moreDirectories)
update(directories)
console.log(update(directories))
```

Comment: Works like a charm. thx. I have one more. now lets say we wanted to run a different array through this like ` const directories2 = [{ParentId:60...}, ...] ` with a different parentId like 60? How would I modify the code above to accommodate that? Basically I am switching through folder structures and each parent has a different Ids.  In ours here it would be different arrays with different parent ids

Comment: Create multiple `flatlist` variables (or use an object to build it dynamically by structure id) and pass it into the equation instead of using the parent scope. `const update = (updates, flatlist) => {`

Comment: I found how to do it. I need to dynamically change the key on the parent.
`const flatlist = {
[DYNAMIC KEY WHICH IS THE ID]: {Id:1,Name:"test",SubDirectoryCount:10,Files:[]}
};`

Comment: I don't understand. `flatlist` represents an entire directory structure. Each key in flatlist represents a single folder. So if you wanted a new independent directory structure wouldn't you need a new flatlist?

Comment: I figured it out.  thanks for all of your help. much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You could tackle this using [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce%5D).

Pass in the original `main` array to the `reduce` function and then process each element in `directories` to attach it to `main`.

**Snippet:**

```js
const mainArray = [{
  Id: 1,
  Name: "test",
  SubDirectoryCount: 10,
  Files: []
}];

const directories = [{
    Id: 56,
    Name: "Client 2",
    SubDirectoryCount: 1,
    ParentId: 1,
    Files: []
  },
  {
    Id: 53,
    Name: "Client 3",
    SubDirectoryCount: 1,
    ParentId: 1,
    Files: []
  },
  {
    Id: 50,
    Name: "Client 4",
    SubDirectoryCount: 1,
    ParentId: 1,
    Files: []
  },
  {
    Id: 48,
    Name: "Client 5",
    SubDirectoryCount: 1,
    ParentId: 53,
    Files: []
  },
  {
    Id: 47,
    Name: "Client 5",
    SubDirectoryCount: 1,
    ParentId: 53,
    Files: []
  },
  {
    Id: 49,
    Name: "Client 5",
    SubDirectoryCount: 1,
    ParentId: 53,
    Files: []
  },
  {
    Id: 47,
    Name: "Client 5",
    SubDirectoryCount: 1,
    ParentId: 49,
    Files: []
  }
];

const search = (data, parentId) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].Id === parentId) {
      return data[i];
    }

    if (data[i].SubDirectories) {
      return search(data[i].SubDirectories, parentId);
    }
  }
};

const final = directories.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => {
  const parent = search(previousValue, currentValue.ParentId);
  parent.SubDirectories = parent.SubDirectories || [];
  parent.SubDirectories.push(currentValue);

  return previousValue;
}, mainArray);

console.info(final);
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Since objects in JavaScript are passed by reference you could use it to your advantage reducing your original list into a object `{ [id]: [object] }` (to access parent 'immediately') then filtering to find any root directory while populating the `files` attribute of your parent (if have one).

---

**Original**
Why not merging both arrays with [Array.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and do it with [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and just filtering any root directory for your treetable

```js
['aaa', 'bb'].concat(['ab', 'bc'])
> Array(4) [ "aaa", "bb", "ab", "bc" ]
```

```js
const directories = [
  {
    Id: 1,
    Name: 'test'
  },
  {
    Id: 56,
    Name: 'Client 2',
    ParentId: 1
  },
  {
    Id: 53,
    Name: 'Client 3',
    ParentId: 1
  },
  {
    Id: 50,
    Name: 'Client 4',
    ParentId: 1
  },
  {
    Id: 48,
    Name: 'Client 5',
    ParentId: 53
  },
  {
    Id: 47,
    Name: 'Client 5',
    ParentId: 53
  },
  {
    Id: 47,
    Name: 'Client 5',
    ParentId: 53
  }
]

const files = directories.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur.Id] = cur
  return acc
}, {})

const rootDir = directories.filter((dir) => {
  if (dir.ParentId) {
    if (!files[dir.ParentId].dirs) {
      files[dir.ParentId].dirs = []
    }
    files[dir.ParentId].dirs.push(dir)
    return false
  }
  return true
})

console.log(rootDir)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have one flat list of all directories, you can iterate once.

```js
const mainArray = [{Id:1,Name:"test",SubDirectoryCount:10,Files:[]}];
const directories = [{Id:56,Name:"Client 2",SubDirectoryCount:1,ParentId:1,Files:[]},{Id:53,Name:"Client 3",SubDirectoryCount:1,ParentId:1,Files:[]},{Id:50,Name:"Client 4",SubDirectoryCount:1,ParentId:1,Files:[]},{Id:48,Name:"Client 5",SubDirectoryCount:1,ParentId:53,Files:[]},{Id:47,Name:"Client 5",SubDirectoryCount:1,ParentId:53,Files:[]},{Id:49,Name:"Client 5",SubDirectoryCount:1,ParentId:53,Files:[]}];

// create flat list
const tmp = mainArray.concat(directories);
tmp.forEach(directory => {
  const parent = tmp.find(item => item.Id === directory.ParentId);

  if(parent) {
      parent.SubDirectories = parent.SubDirectories || [];
      parent.SubDirectories.push(directory)
  }
});

console.log(mainArray)
```

Comment: Howdy!, So this works great! I need an update though. So basically I have this call on material UI treeview toggle that fetches the directories when toggled and it adds more directories to the array. So, when I make that call again it keeps duplicating everything. I am trying to find the best way to not push into array if its already there... Ive tried a few things but, no dice. much appreciated. thx

Comment: That's a different problem because it might invalidate the mapping. It sounds like you need to store the directories list in a static associative array and rebuild them from scratch each time. This is better anyway. I'll add another answer after my meeting.